# I can't close dialog in jointJS

Tags: javascript, dialog, jointjs, rappid

[Here is and a screenshot I uploaded for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtVKp.png)  I have edited my post, according to your advice in comments, posting my updated version of my code.I enclose in /**/ my original post for helping you.

```
/*In jointJS I try using a `ui.dialog` to delete all my graph with the following code:

    var dialog = new joint.ui.Dialog({
                width: 400,
                title: 'Create new process',
                content: '<b>Cleanup current drawing?</b>',
                closeButton: false,
                buttons: [
                    { action: 'ok', content: 'OK' },
                    { action: 'cancel', content: 'CANCEL' }
                ]
            });

            dialog.on('action:ok', this.graph.clear, this.graph);
            dialog.on('action:cancel', dialog.close, dialog);
            dialog.open();
        },

After pressing OK button I successfully delete my graph but my dialog still remains without being able to delete it.

Any help please? */
```

Here is my updated code which unfortunately still doesn't work as expected. I remind you that in this dialog form which displays an OK and Cancel button I want the following ones:

1)When pressing OK I want to :
a)Delete my current graph And
b)Close my dialog

2)When pressing Cancel I want to:
Close my dialog (Which in my initial version worked successfylly with `dialog.close`)

```
openNew: function() {
        // By pressing Create New Process button, a popup form asks for 
        //our confirmation before deleting current graph
        var dialog = new joint.ui.Dialog({
            width: 400,
            title: 'Create new process',
            content: '<b>Cleanup current drawing?</b>',
            closeButton: false,
            buttons: [
                { action: 'ok', content: 'OK' },
                { action: 'cancel', content: 'CANCEL' }
            ]
        });

        //Since in 'action:ok' of dialog.on the 3rd parameter is used in the
        //callback of multi_hand we must pass dialog and graph both together.To do so
        //we enclose them in an object named together and we pass it instead

        together= {dialog : dialog, graph : this.graph};

        //Since jointJS supports assigning multiple events for same handler
        //BUT NOT multiple handlers for the same event we create function multi_hand
        multi_hand: function (together)
        {  
          together.graph.clear(); 
          together.dialog.close();
        }
        dialog.on('action:ok', multi_hand, together);
        dialog.on('action:cancel', dialog.close, dialog);
        dialog.open();
    },
```

By using this new code my joinjtJS project crashes unexpectedly.
How will I make OK button work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem this way and I just want to share it with all of you as a reference.

```
openNew: function() {
    var dialog = new joint.ui.Dialog({
            width: 400,
            title: 'Create new process',
            content: '<b>Cleanup current drawing?</b>',
            closeButton: false,
            buttons: [
                { action: 'ok', content: 'OK' },
                { action: 'cancel', content: 'CANCEL' }
            ]
        });

        dialog.on('action:ok', this.graph.clear, this.graph);
        dialog.on('action:ok action:cancel', dialog.close, dialog);
        dialog.open();
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

The third argument in `dialog.on` is the context passed into the callback function (2nd argument). It says, what is bind to `this` in the callback function.
In your example is not clear where the `graph` is defined, if it is really `this.graph`. However, you can simply do it like in the following example, without passing the context:

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: 650,
    height: 400,
    model: graph,
    linkPinning: false
});

var r = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 40 },
}).addTo(graph);

var dialog = new joint.ui.Dialog({
    width: 400,
    title: 'Confirm',
    content: '<b>Are you sure?</b>',
    buttons: [
        { action: 'yes', content: 'Yes' },
        { action: 'no', content: 'No' }
    ]
});

dialog.on('action:yes', function() {
    graph.clear();
    dialog.close()
});

dialog.on('action:no', dialog.close, dialog);
dialog.open();
```

if the `graph` is defined on `this`:

```
dialog.on('action:yes', function() {
    this.graph.clear();
    dialog.close();
}, this);
```

Comment: try `console.log(this.graph)` somewhere in the `openNew` function body. It shouldn't be 'undefined'

Comment: I solved my problem this way and I just want to share it with all of you as a reference.